# Spring Boot : javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query When Using @Transactional Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I am working on Spring Boot (v1.5.22.RELEASE) and Hibernate 5.4.20.Final [pom.xml attached bellow]. Also tried with Spring Boot (v2.2.2) but I am getting same error.

In my project the database is dynamic. Based on the request, the database is changed.

I am using SessionBuilderImpl class to set database and get Current Session.

When trying to update the table [Using HQL or NativeSQL] , the following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl ERROR WHILE UPDATING APP DEPLOYMENT HISTORY STATUS { SET `is_current_exec` = 0 } IN DATABASE { AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl.updateAllStatus }javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1608)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.entity.daoimpl.AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl.updateAllStatus(AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.updateAllStatus(Unknown Source)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.entity.serviceimpl.AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl.updateAllStatus(AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl.java:55)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.entity.serviceimpl.AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b450460.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.entity.serviceimpl.AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b3a1110.updateAllStatus(<generated>)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.core.AppHandler.resetAppDeploymentHsitoryStatus(AppHandler.java:121)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.core.AppHandler.setBasicSetup(AppHandler.java:80)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.core.AppUninstallInitiator.setBasicSetup(AppUninstallInitiator.java:45)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.core.AppUninstallInitiator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77c48f3c.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.core.AppUninstallInitiator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$69685b24.setBasicSetup(<generated>)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.rmq.UndeploymentQueueConsumer.init(UndeploymentQueueConsumer.java:87)
        at com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.rmq.UndeploymentQueueConsumer.handleDelivery(UndeploymentQueueConsumer.java:101)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Constants Used**
Constants.CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mariadb://%s:%s/";

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {
   @Autowired
   private DbProperties dbProperties;

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernateSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.*");
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.testcompany.app.fw.amt.*");
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
   }
   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
     HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
     transactionManager.setSessionFactory(hibernateSessionFactory().getObject());
     transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
     return transactionManager;
   }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(String.format(AppConstants.CONNECTION_URL, dbProperties.getDbHost(), dbProperties.getDbPort()));
        dataSource.setUsername(dbProperties.getDbUser());
        dataSource.setPassword(dbProperties.getDbPassword());
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(30);
        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        return dataSource; 
    }
    public Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect");
        settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
        return settings;
    }

}
```

**AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl.java**

```
 @Override
 @Transactional
 public void updateAllStatus(String clientDbName) throws ToolException {
      try{
           appDeploymentHistoryDao.updateAllStatus(clientDbName);
        }catch(HibernateException he){
            logger.error("***** <<< ERROR IN AppDeploymentHistoryServiceImpl.updateAllStatus >>> *****" , he);
        }
    }
```

**AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl.java**

```
    @Override
    public void updateAllStatus(String clientDbName) {
        try {
            Session session = sessionBuilder.getClientSession(clientDbName);
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE `app_deployement_history` SET `is_current_exec` = 0 ");
            query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("ERROR WHILE UPDATING APP DEPLOYMENT HISTORY STATUS { SET `is_current_exec` = 0 } IN DATABASE { AppDeploymentHistoryDaoImpl.updateAllStatus }" + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        }
    }
```

**SessionBuilderImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class SessionBuilderImpl implements SessionBuilder {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionBuilderImpl.class);
    private static final String EXECPTION_MSG = "Error while exchanging database in session : Super amdin ";
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public Session getClientSession(String dbName) throws HibernateException {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            Connection connection = sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().
                                                   getService(ConnectionProvider.class).getConnection();
            connection.setCatalog(dbName);
            org.hibernate.SessionBuilder hibernateSessionBuilder = sessionFactory.withOptions();
            currentSession = hibernateSessionBuilder.connection(connection).openSession();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("***** <<< HIBERNATE EXCEPTION : IN HIBERNATE_CONFIG : getSessionByDb(String dbName) >>> *****");
        }
        return currentSession;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getCurrentConnection() throws HibernateException {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) currentSession).connection();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.testcompany.app.fw.amt</groupId>
    <artifactId>AMTTool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-rc1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaxt</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaxt-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.restlet.talend.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jspresso-repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jspresso.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <name>AMTTool</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Is your `@Transactional` annotation of `spring` package or `javax.transaction` package?

Comment: I am using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: Try renaming `hibernateTransactionManager` function to `transactionManager`, I think, your transaction manager is not bound with spring aop. Check [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-first-example), it mentions that if you have name other than this then you need to provide `transaction-manager` attribute, so I guess spring AOP expecting that name only.

Comment: Tried after changing the function name to transactionManager, Still same exception exist.

Comment: Simple operation on entity object like `save` working?

Comment: Yes, I tried with entity save and its working, Here is the Code snippet   
 ```Session session = sessionBuilder.getClientSession(clientDbName);
     session.save(appDeploymentHistory); ```

Comment: Then I think, this is something related to modifying query which is by passing current persistence context and directly dealing with database and might not be executed with transaction, try open manual transaction and commit after query and check if that works.

Comment: The problem is your code and it is actually dangerous. You have a session and a connection leak. **Never** use `openSession` to get a session when using `@Transactional`. it will open a new session and connection etc. outside the management of Spring. What you should be doing instead is simplify your code, ditch plain hibernate and use JPA. Then use the underlying multi-tenant support in Hibernate to switch the schema when needed.

Comment: Another thing is that you are messing around with the `current_session_context_class` don't. Or at least set it to Spring as you are currently making it run outside of spring.

Comment: Finally your solution looks quite convulted. Using Hibernate in that way to execute a schema switch and a simple SQL query. Instead just use JDBC. Inject a `JdbcTemplate` use a `ConnectionCallback` to switch the schema (and keep the old one), then execute the query and in the end switch back the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt, the save and other cases are working here as well unless you have code other than posted here.

The problem with your code is that you are creating another session manually, the session bound with transaction manager(which spring is managing) is not aware of this, so your changes will not reflect.

Since, update/delete here is modifying native query, hibernate throwing error because it is not finding any transaction associated with it.

#### TL;DR

To verify it, I did little digging and created config same as you posted

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JpaProperties.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
class CustomJpaConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jpaProperties.getDatasource().getUrl());
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(jpaProperties.getDatasource().getDriver());
        dataSource.setUsername(jpaProperties.getDatasource().getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(jpaProperties.getDatasource().getPassword());
        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.jpa.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", jpaProperties.getDialect());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "" + jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                jpaProperties.getDdlMode() == null ? "none" : jpaProperties.getDdlMode());
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

First I checked with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` if it gives the same error or not.

So, I created a small entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_on", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private final Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    
    // Ignoring getters and setters
}
```

Then, I executed the insert case and found following logs<sup>1</sup>

```
2021-04-09 22:47:15.050 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@20163008] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:47:15.050 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@3436d3d7] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@60ef30b1] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:47:15.050 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:47:15.050 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.addUser]
2021-04-09 22:47:15.058 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@3436d3d7] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@60ef30b1] bound to thread [main]
Hibernate: insert into users (id, created_on, email, name, updated_on, version) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-04-09 22:47:15.104 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.addUser]
2021-04-09 22:47:15.116 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:47:15.116 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@3436d3d7] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@60ef30b1] from thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:47:15.116 TRACE 63230 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@20163008] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [main]
```

You can see clearly see that insert statement executing and I did check the `id` returned, it was non-null.

Now, I used the session builder code you have posted and with that logs were

```
2021-04-09 22:45:42.300 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@60ef30b1] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:45:42.301 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@3f40568e] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@3436d3d7] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:45:42.301 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:45:42.301 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.addUser]
2021-04-09 22:45:42.332 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.addUser]
2021-04-09 22:45:42.335 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:45:42.335 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@3f40568e] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@3436d3d7] from thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:45:42.335 TRACE 63184 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@60ef30b1] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [main]
```

Notice, in both logs the transaction synchronization manager starting and closing transaction but in former logs, it was issuing the insert statements and in later not, because you created the session again using `Connection` object, transaction manager never sees it.

Now, if I execute the delete case with first code, it works fine because transaction is known to the session but with your code session is different and that doesn't have any transaction associated, check below logs for both

```
2021-04-09 22:55:06.122 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@62d6ac] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:55:06.122 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@103e9972] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@359ea595] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:55:06.122 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:55:06.122 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.deleteById]
2021-04-09 22:55:06.123 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@103e9972] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@359ea595] bound to thread [main]
Hibernate: delete from users where id = 2
2021-04-09 22:55:06.169 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.deleteById]
2021-04-09 22:55:06.170 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:55:06.171 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@103e9972] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@359ea595] from thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:55:06.171 TRACE 63280 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@62d6ac] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [main]
```

And with your session builder code

```
2021-04-09 22:56:18.993 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@912747d] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:56:18.993 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@78ea700f] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4fef4f96] to thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:56:18.994 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:56:18.994 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.deleteById]
2021-04-09 22:56:19.028 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.example.jpa.service.UserService.deleteById] after exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
2021-04-09 22:56:19.029 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
2021-04-09 22:56:19.029 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : Winning rollback rule is: null
2021-04-09 22:56:19.029 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute    : No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
2021-04-09 22:56:19.032 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2021-04-09 22:56:19.032 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@78ea700f] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4fef4f96] from thread [main]
2021-04-09 22:56:19.033 TRACE 63399 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@912747d] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [main]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

#### Conclusion

You would have to use the same session which is provided by the session factory, because spring's transaction flow only aware of that.

---

<sup>1</sup> Logs are produced using 2 properties logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=trace and hibernate.show_sql=true